# Trigger for before insert to add in x number of days to a date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add x number of days to a variable within a table by deriving another date from the same table.

For example, in my `BILLING` table, it has 2 dates - `BillDate` and `DueDate`.
And so, I am trying to add a trigger before the insertion, such that it will takes in the BillDate and add 30 days to derive the DueDate.

While doing so, I got a bunch of errors, as follows:
[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=94e5555e4d511c478b5ff7492d193cb9)

```
CREATE TABLE BILLING
(
    BillDate DATE NOT NULL,
    DueDate DATE NULL
);

-- Got ORA-24344: success with compilation error
CREATE TRIGGER duedate_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON BILLING 
FOR EACH ROW

begin
     set DueDate = :new.DueDate: + 30

end;

-- Got ORA-04098: trigger 'FIDDLE_FBHUOBXMWRPYBBXPIKTW.DUEDATE_TRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation
INSERT INTO BILLING
VALUES ((Date '2020-07-23'), NULL);
```

For the insertion, I have tried removing the `NULL`, but still I am getting a bunch of errors.
Any ideas?

Also, in the event, if the insertion statement also does includes in the due date too, will this affects the trigger? Trying to cater for 2 scenarios, generate a due date if not give, else if given, check if it is within 30 days from BillDate and update it... (likely I may have overthink/ overestimated that this is doable?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER duedate_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON BILLING 
FOR EACH ROW
begin
     :new.DueDate := :new.BillDate + 30;

end;


INSERT INTO BILLING (BillDate ) values (sysdate);
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting a `ORA-00947: not enough values`.. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=59d7fc185f81f4ec5e54e6baeeab4f33)

Comment: Did you look at my insert statement?   I specified BillDate column.  That is not what your fiddle shows.

Comment: yes I did (the previous fiddle was of the wrong one, my bad) but even so, after using your code - [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=824fce813aa2974b2db62fa782d67a72), it is still showing a different error...

Comment: @j.hall You should terminate PL/SQL block with forward slash (`/`) like in SQL*Plus to make it compilable in fiddle. Check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4fd564841d19e5caecb9171137850810). Anyway, it is better to test this in your system instead of some environtment, because you'll do it in that same system.

Comment: @astentx Noted on that, was not aware of the `/` in fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER duedate_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON billing
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
     v_dueDate_derive NUMBER;
BEGIN
     v_dueDate_derive = 30;
     :new.DueDate = :new.BillDate + v_dueDate_derive;
END;
```

Days can be easily added by +, so it should not be the problem.

I believe there may be something wrong with INSERT itself.
Could you try to put INSERT like this?

```
INSERT INTO BILLING
VALUES (TO_DATE('2020-07-23'), NULL);
```

Comment: And what is the difference between this and previous answer?

Comment: Normalization of the trigger, usage is actually the same, but also wanted to add comment about insert and comment to this, so I just put everything I did not to force searching through questions. I believe its fine.

Comment: @Anseal during the addition part, is it by default that oracle uses `days` (30 in this case)? Or something else needs to be set, eg. if i need to add it by months?

Comment: @j.hall Days is default. But you can use add_months function or add interval literal. [Example](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals#interval).